# Is the spectral norm a Lipschitz function with respect to the spectral norm?

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, lipschitz-functions, matrix-norms, spectral-norm

I was wondering if the spectral norm is a Lipschitz function with respect to the spectral norm. How can we prove whether it is or not? In other words, is $$\big| \|X\| - \|Y\| \big| \le L \|X-Y\|$$ for some $L$?

Comment: I'm not familiar with spectral norm, but if it is a norm, can't you just use the triangle inequality to get $|\|X\| - \|Y\|| \leq \|X - Y\|$?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. We can use the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any norm is Lipschitz of rank 1 with respect to itself. This follows from the traingle inequality.

Since $\|X\| \le \|Y\|+\|X-Y\|$ we have $\|X\| -\|Y\| \le \|X-Y\|$. Reversing the roles of $X,Y$ gives $\|Y\| -\|X\| \le \|X-Y\|$ and combining these gives $| \|X\|-\|Y\| | \le \|X-Y\|$.